# For-loop of rownames input to function

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a function tryCatch that outputs something like this:

```
> s1 <- tryCatch(survdiff(Surv(as.numeric(as.character(ClinicalDataHep$new_death))[ind_clin],ClinicalDataHep$death_event[ind_clin])~event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum]), error = function(e) return(NA))
> s1
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(as.numeric(as.character(ClinicalDataHep$new_death))[ind_clin], 
    ClinicalDataHep$death_event[ind_clin]) ~ event_rna[ind_gene, 
    ind_tum])

                                N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=0 72       41     41.1  0.000223   0.00278
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=1  4        4      3.9  0.002345   0.00278

 Chisq= 0  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.958
```

From this output it is possible to calculate a p-value like this:

```
> p.val <- 1 - pchisq(s1$chisq, length(s1$n) - 1)
> p.val
[1] 0.9579535
```

I would like to make a for-loop in the first function that takes all possible `ind_gene` in `TryCatch` which is defined from `rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver)` and **get p-values for all the different rownames**.
Examples of `ind_gene`:

```
> head(rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver))
[1] "hsa-let-7a-2-3p" "hsa-let-7a-3p"   "hsa-let-7a-5p"   "hsa-let-7b-3p"   "hsa-let-7b-5p"  
[6] "hsa-let-7c-3p"
```

Something like:

```
for (i in rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver)) 
{TryCatch...
}
```

Comment: I would need more information.  Can you use nonsense data and provide a better example?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is wrapping a function around everything and use `sapply`. This way you do not have to change your code much. To make the loop successful, we must handle the cases where the `tryCatch` catches an error. This is done with an `ifelse` on the p-value.

```
mycatch <- function(ind_gene){
    s1 <- tryCatch(survdiff(Surv(as.numeric(as.character(
        ClinicalDataHep$new_death)
    )[ind_clin], ClinicalDataHep$death_event[ind_clin]) ~
        event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum]),
    error = function(e) return(NA))

    p.val <- ifelse(is.na(s1), # Condition
                    NA,        # Return if s1 = NA
                    1 - pchisq(s1$chisq, length(s1$n) - 1)) 
    p.val
}

sapply(rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver), mycatch)
```

Notice how I have split your lines of code - it is generally considered good practice to not have too long lines of code. I use a max of 65 since I occasionally paste it into TeX documents but as you can see by the grey box above, they can be much wider.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpfull: However the sapply gave me this:  sapply(rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver), mycatch)                                      Error in s1$chisq : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: However the function works: > p.val <- 1 - pchisq(s1$chisq, length(s1$n) - 1)
> p.val
[1] 0.9579535

Comment: @user2300940 I cannot reproduce your error since I do not have your data. Perhaps a reproducible sample? Otherwise, a workaround that error could be to use `s1[["chisq"]]` instead of `s1$chisq` since the `s1´ seems to not be a recursive object, see `?"$"`.

Comment: Error in s1[["chisq"]] : subscript out of bounds. It is hard to make a reproducable example since the data is rather huge

Comment: Perhaps one of your cases makes an error? Then your `tryCatch` sets `s1` to `NA` which would correctly give the error `s1$chisq : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`, since, indeed, then `s1` would be an atomic vector of length 1.

Comment: If this is the case, make `p.val <- ifelse(!is.na(s1), 1 - pchisq(s1$chisq, length(s1$n) - 1), NA)`, i.e. if `s1` returns properly, calculate the p-value, otherwise if error, set p-value to `NA`.